# Get html with "fetch" no body

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I would like to get an HTML page this one :https://cas.univ-lemans.fr/cas/login, but my response haven't body.... 
Anyone have a idea ?

my code :

```js
this.header = {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "mode": "no-cors",
    "Content-Type" : "text/html"
};
fetch(url, this.header)
    .then(function(response){
         console.log(response);
         response.text();
    })
    .then((body) => {
         console.log(body);
    })
```

console :

[image: Console result]

Answer (score 0):

As per the response object in the console, response.ok is false that is why you are receiving body for it. Also as per the warning, there is a Cross-Origin issue in fetching the resource. Kindly, go through the following CORS origin link to understand how it works and how you can configure it.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS.

Also as your issues looks to be similar to CORB, it will better if you have a look in the CORB security implementation and how you can by pass it. 
https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/corb-for-developers